# Changing button symbol after the toggle is complete

Tags: jquery, button, toggle

So, I have a button showing and hiding a div with the ID of "details" and a button with the ID of "more" while changing symbols on click with an up and down arrow. (It starts with details hidden and the down chevron visible. What I would actually like is for the image swap (class change) to happen after the toggle animation is complete instead of on click.
How would I do this?

```
('#more').click(function() {
  $('#details').toggle('slow');

});
$('#more').click(function() 
{ 
  if ($(this).html() == '<i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>') 
  { 
     $(this).html('<i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>'); 
  } 
  else 
  { 
     $(this).html('<i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>'); 
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) has a callback. Use it!

```
$('#more').click(function() {
  var $el = $(this);

  $('#details').toggle('slow', function() {
    if ($el.html() == '<i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>') { 
      $el.html('<i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>'); 
    } 
    else { 
      $el.html('<i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>'); 
    } 
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly! I am very new to coding and just getting my to function as it did was quite a journey.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#more').click(function() { 
     var $i = $(this).find('i');
     $('#details').toggle('slow' function(){
         $i.toggleClass("icon-chevron-up icon-chevron-down"); 
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The toggle method accepts a function as a second parameter that will be called when the function is done. So this should do the trick:

```
('#more').click(function() {
    var self = this;  // you need the self reference in order to keep a reference to the clicked element
  $('#details').toggle('slow', function () 
      { 
          if ($(self).html() == '<i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>') { 
              $(self).html('<i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>'); 
          } 
          else { 
              $(self).html('<i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>'); 
          } 
      });
});
```